# Schedule Python script with crontab doesn't work

Tags: python, cron

Trying to schedule a python code in crontab, but it doesn't work.
How Can I understand the reason why?
I've already add cron and termianl to Full disk access, so this shouldn't be a problem

everything works fine when I run in terminal command
`python /users/myuser/slots_update.py`

Crontab command which doesnt'work:
`45 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /users/myuser/slots_update.py`

Python script (put different sql inside to make it simplier)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[2]:


# importing the required libraries
import gspread
import pandas as pd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# In[50]:


# define the scope
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

# add credentials to the account
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('key.json', scope)

# authorize the clientsheet 
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


# In[51]:


# get the instance of the Spreadsheet
sheet = client.open('EGE_slots1')

# get the first sheet of the Spreadsheet
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(0)


# In[ ]:


sheet_instance.col_count


# In[52]:


sheet_instance.cell(col=1,row=1)


# In[12]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from datetime import datetime as dt


# In[13]:


connection = create_engine('postgresql://')


# In[47]:


slots = pd.read_sql("""

select * from teachers
                       """,connection)


# In[53]:


sheet_instance.update('A2',slots.values.tolist())


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: Since you say the script works when you run it directly, I believe this question should go on superuser.stackexchange.com rather than here, as it seems to be a problem specific to your use of Cron and not code-related

Answer (score 1):

Use full path to the json file.

`creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('key.json', scope)` --> `creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/a/b/c/key.json', scope)`

Comment: Thank you for answer! But unfortunately, doesn't help (of course I changed time in cron to check it now :) )

Comment: @SmirnovaAnna This is a problem for sure. You may have another problem..